# Why does cmd cant run the python file on desktop, it keeps on showing "[Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

So basically the file is on the desktop/pythonBot folder, but the cmd cant open it up? The code I type in is `python bot.py`. I followed this dude's guide here: 
https://www.smartspate.com/how-to-create-a-telegram-bot-with-ai-in-30-lines-of-code-in-python/
(Sorry I am just a senior high student with no coding background)

Comment: How about you show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From screenshot i guessed you have .py in another directory.

cmd is searching for "bot.py" file in C:\Users\s9800 directory.From error i can guess your bot.py file is in another direcotry.Provide full of .py file

> > How to run .py file

1st way :open cmd,drag and drop .py file to cmd and press enter

2nd way:Go to directory where your .py file is.Wrtie "cmd" in address bar ,it will open cmd ,type file name and press enter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not in the correct directory, us `cd` to navigate to `desktop/pythonBot` or alternatively, use the full path when running the file.

Comment: cmd is searching  for "bot.py" file in C:\Users\s9800 directory.From error i can guess your bot.py file is in another direcotry.Provide full of .py file(open cmd,drag and drop .py file to cmd and press enter)